# Pass parameter to action dispatcher

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I have a class which dispatches `Actions` from a queue. However, my `InvokeLater` only takes in an `Action`, without any parameters.

Here is my `Dispatcher`:

```
public class Dispatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly Queue<Action> tasks = new Queue<Action>();
    public static Dispatcher Instance = null;

    static Dispatcher()
    {
        Instance = new Dispatcher();
    }

    private Dispatcher(){ }

    public void InvokeLater(Action task)
    {
        lock (tasks)
        {
            tasks.Enqueue(task);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        while (tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            Action task = null;

            lock (tasks)
            {
                if (tasks.Count > 0)
                {
                    task = tasks.Dequeue();
                }
            }

            task();
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
var action = new Action(RequestPrediction);
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

Where `RequestPrediction` is a parameterless function -- which I would like to change so that it (`RequestPrediction`) takes an `int` argument.

How can I change my `Dispatcher` so that I can do something like:

```
var action = new Action(RequestPrediction);
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action,5);
```

?

Comment: generic class of action ``Action<T>``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution:

```
var action = new Action(() => RequestPrediction(5));
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

Otherwise, you'd have to develop your framework and you'd end up with something which tries to look like the existing [TPL library in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) or existing [`Dispatcher` implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). Which are other, even better suggestions.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda function. It will be automatically converted to an Action. Instead of

```
var action = new Action(RequestPrediction);
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

You can use

```
Action action = () => RequestPrediction();
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

Or if you prefer implicitly typed local variables (the var keyword):

```
var action = new Action(() => RequestPrediction());
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

This way, you can add parameters in the calling site:

```
Action action = () => RequestPrediction(5);
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

Or

```
var action = new Action(() => RequestPrediction(5));
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokeLater(action);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is correct! However, BartoszKP got to it first ;P